# Integration of Emacs/LuaLaTeX with Evince/Zathura not working in Ubuntu 18.04. How can I fix it?

Tags: latex, emacs, evince, lua, zathura

After my recent upgrade (per new install) to Ubuntu 18.04, I have started having quite some troubles with my tool chain (Emacs, Lualatex, Evince). I am using forward/backward search to approximate WYSIWYG LaTeX editing.

Evince has started to crash on recompiling/updating LuaLaTeX. Then I tried zathura (another PDF viewer) instead, and after a view tries, similar crashes happen with zathura as well. Zathura after a while cannot even be started anymore by the commands Emacs issues to control zathura.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the corresponding emacs, evince, and zathura packages as well as some "standard" emacs extensions from the ubuntu package repository.

The relevant portion of my .emacs:

```
(package-initialize)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'electric-pair-mode) 
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'show-paren-mode)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)

(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'outline-minor-mode)

(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'company-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode)
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Zathura")))
```

Emacs generates the following call:

```
zathura file.pdf --synctex-forward 200:0:sometexinclude.tex -x "emacsclient
+%{line} %{input}"
```

Called like this, zathura (I do not use a zathura config file) exhibits the following:

```
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  zathura file.pdf
--synctex-forward 200:0:sometexinclude.tex -x
```

Evince also crashes with SIGSEGV which leads me to believe that is a problem independent of the viewers.

The last thing I found out is that taking away the synctex.gz file makes it  possible to start zathura and view the pdf output. But this is of course no desirable solution. However, I was not able to quickly find out how to find the core dump and make it human readable in this case. (That might exceed the scope of my problem.)

A description of that issue occurring with large documents in an OS X setting is described [here](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/286): For me, it also happens more often the longer (60+ pages) the documents are, however, in my case under Linux.

Hope to get some help? (Should I transfer/share this question to/with the emacs community?)

Answer (score 1):

**One solution** that seems to work for me at the moment is to **leave out** the line

```
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
```

from my .emacs config. So, the **minimum config** to get forward/backward search to work again seems to be:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
```

using evince (by default) and with one more line *for using zathura*:

```
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Zathura")))
```

Additionally, I changed from `\include` and `\includeonly` to a scheme **commenting out unused latex includes**. My theory is that hyperlinks (e.g. to bibrefs, sections, etc.) to pages maintained in the latex and synctex outputs but **NOT** generated into the pdf might cause some trouble in both of the PDF viewers I used.

***A more reliable solution*** is to delete the `.synctex.gz` file. This for both evince and zathura solves the problem which will then only return every once in a while. However, I haven't been able to find a better solution so far. I should say that this is not really a practical solution anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, my hope was too soon: synctex is part of the problem, but the cause seems to lie in my (UTF8-coded) bib files. I am not sure what happens, however, when commenting out some of the biber includes, things seem to work again after clean-up and recompilation. However, even bib files without biber warnings, once re-included, will lead the PDF viewers to crash. Sorry, I am left with a peculiar problem here.

Comment: I switched back to using \include and \includeonly. Additionally, I am taking care that no references point "outside" the generated PDF by including bibliography, glossary, other listof's. For the time being, it seems to work.

Comment: Switch to pdf-tools, see my answer to a corresponding question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436115/4736

Comment: Thanks. The discussion there seems to conclude that there is actually a bug. However, I haven't found any reports. Can anybody point to something recent and potentially related?

Comment: I found a more general description that suggests this issue is a more fundamental one occurring in several settings: https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/286

Comment: Astonishing. So syncTeX might be the culprit. Would you go and post a bug report on the maintainers github page: https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex/issues -? By the way, I changed from okular to pdf-tools, because okular is more and more unstable these days. Sigh.

Comment: Apparently, but I'm missing the complete overview of all the dependencies. Yes, I can do that. Haven't been using okular in a while, but can reproduce that issue with two other PDF viewers anyway :)

Comment: Ok, posted on github now: https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex/issues/29

Comment: I'll watch as well, if the maintainer reacts. SyncTeX is important in the whole TeX & Friends world.